# Grab first segment of URL in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a URL saved to a variable in Perl and I'd like to strip off everything after the domain name.  I think grabbing everything to the left of the third slash should do it.  I do want to keep the protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
($url) = $url =~ m! (.+?\w) (?: /|\z) !x;
```